# Can a Google Chrome Extension Change The Appearance of the Browser Like A Theme?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am interested in creating a Google Chrome Extension that changes the appearance of the Google Chrome toolbar for the active tab ONLY IF I'm visiting a particular domain.  This change in appearance would be similar to what's already possible with a Google Chrome theme.

I want to create this functionality because I develop and test web applications on both a staging and a production server that have similar domain names, and I'd like an easy visual way to tell whether I'm on either the staging or production version.

So, for example, if I'm facing the staging server, the color of the browser tab would be a light green but if I'm facing the production server, it would be red to alert me that I'm playing with live data.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there's no API to style the browser from an extension.

I would suggest altering the favicon instead to visually differentiate the tab, which can be easily done with a content script in an extension.

Perhaps even more useful is styling the background of the page from an extension, e.g. with unobtrusive light-colored stripes - as long as you don't care that the design is not 100% what the customer sees.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions.  I like the idea of using unobtrusive light-colored stripes - would that be accomplished by injecting some CSS into the page?

Comment: Yes. See documentation on [Content Scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#registration).

Comment: @Xan, But themes allow us to modify UI areas outside of the "page area". How do I combine theme with an extension? Do I need the user to download two of them separately or is there a better way?